# Calculating the matrix element of $q^4$

Tags: quantum-mechanics

So we have a generalized coordinate $q$ and we want to know the matrix element:
$$(q^4)_{ij}= \langle\, i|q^4|j \,\rangle\;.$$
What I have seen is that we get the same result if we do $\langle\, i|q|j\, \rangle^4$ or  $\langle\, i|q^2|j\, \rangle^2$.

Is that always the case with matrix elements? Or just under certain conditions? Would it also work if I wanted to calculate lets say the expectation value of $x^2$ or the one of some general function $\psi(x)$?

Additional info: $|i\, \rangle$ and $|j\, \rangle$ are elements of the eigenbasis of a harmonic oscillator.

Answer (score 2):

This is not generally true. For example, consider the matrix
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & \lambda \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$
Then we have
$$(A_{12})^4 = \lambda^4, \quad ((A^2)_{12})^2 = 4 \lambda^2, \quad (A^4)_{12} = 4 \lambda.$$

These are all different things. They will only be equal in rather special cases.